# How to you fix this code for delegate void system.Action error?

Tags: asp.net, delegates, action

This is my code

```
private void try_catch(Action method)
{
    if (method == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
    try
    {
        Connect();
        method();
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        DisConnect();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        DisConnect();
    }
    finally
    {
        DisConnect();
    }
}
```

and this is error

> Using the generic type 'System.Action' requires '1' type arguments

Comment: Did you even try to research it?

Comment: Please help me, I am newbie

Comment: Please share the call to this function, and which line the error happens on.